# Cannot connect to mySql database on Localhost with Notepad as text editor

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection, notepad

It may be similar questions to other in SO but most answers were related to the server configuration or IDE Configuration. 
Here I am trying to achieve the connection to Local Mysql Database using Notepad as text editor for my Classes and CMD to run. So, here I have a Folder called 'Learning' where my register.java and register.class lies. My **register.java** has:

```
jbsubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");         
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo","root","LJV9txSRof44Xmvk");

        String name = tfname.getText();
        String email = tfemail.getText();
        String pass = tpfpass.getText();

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO user (name, email, password) VALUES(name, email, pass)");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    });
```

I am aware that Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); not required since v4 & my connector version is 5.1.42.
When using **Class.forName** I get **ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** and when not using **Class.forName** I get **No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname**

### I've tried

- Put the full path to the jarfile in the classpath (including the filename .jar)
- Checked classpath several times for confirmation
- using Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
- Keeping connector in **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin** as well as **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\ext**
- Restarted CMD everytime after classpath changes
- Checked mySql port and connection port above are same

Comment: How do you run your code exactly? Looks like a classpath issue.

Comment: @ipper I run file with CMD & this is my classpath : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar

Comment: What is the exact order of arguments? java -cp ... register

Comment: You probably have other dependencies that you need, hence the other items in your classpath. Have you tried stripping your class to a bare minimum?

Comment: What you list as your "classpath" in your previous comment looks an awful lot like the `PATH` environment variable. `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` are not the same thing.